# Method description from an interface

Tags: c#

I want to write pretty and well-documented code base for my project.
One thing that I want to do is to have method details for my black-box part of the code base. Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The methods summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="numX">Number x.</param>
/// <param name="numY">Number y.</param>
```

But I don't want to write it over and over for every class that extends the interface, instead I want to write it in the interface and have the description appear on all the classes that implement the method.

Is that possible?

Comment: I have always wanted to do this!

Comment: Search around for "comment inheritance". Last I checked, this was possible when [building documentation](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm), but not supported by the IDE during development (would be happy to be wrong).

Comment: You, or we can say if any interface class which having implemented method don't have any documentation then by default interface documentation summary should get populated or if implemented class method having summary then that summary should come(like summary override!)

Comment: @AnkushMadankar before I found out it didn't work like that I thought exactly like that. But alas, it seems that I'll need to copy/paste everything for every implementation by hand.

Comment: http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx can be used

Comment: LIke @bit say it is duplicate.